# allpackages.txt.gz has two different file-sizes?

Tags: debian, package-management, wget

I saw http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2008/12/19/counting-number-of-packages-under-debian-linux/ and I wanted to count the number of packages in testing.

I tried as shared therein :-

```
http://packages.debian.org/testing/allpackages?format=txt.gz
Resolving packages.debian.org (packages.debian.org)... 5.153.231.3, 2001:41c8:1000:21::21:3, 2001:8d8:880:901::1a1:4
Connecting to packages.debian.org (packages.debian.org)|5.153.231.3|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://packages.debian.org/testing/allpackages?format=txt.gz [following]
--2014-10-08 01:52:54--  https://packages.debian.org/testing/allpackages?format=txt.gz
Connecting to packages.debian.org (packages.debian.org)|5.153.231.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1039782 (1015K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘allpackages?format=txt.gz’

100%[======================================================================================================>] 10,39,782   64.0KB/s   in 13s    

$ mv allpackages\?format=txt.gz allpackages.txt.gz

$ gunzip allpackages.txt.gz

$ ll -h allpackages.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish 4.9M Oct  7 23:53 allpackages.txt
```

If however I try to get allpackages without it being compressed I get the following :-

```
$ wget http://packages.debian.org/testing/allpackages
--2014-10-08 01:52:11--  http://packages.debian.org/testing/allpackages
Resolving packages.debian.org (packages.debian.org)... 5.153.231.3, 2001:41c8:1000:21::21:3, 2001:8d8:880:901::1a1:4
Connecting to packages.debian.org (packages.debian.org)|5.153.231.3|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://packages.debian.org/testing/allpackages [following]
--2014-10-08 01:52:11--  https://packages.debian.org/testing/allpackages
Connecting to packages.debian.org (packages.debian.org)|5.153.231.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 10110498 (9.6M) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘allpackages’

 9% [========>                                                                                              ] 9,49,116    55.5KB/s  eta 1m 48s 
Terminated
```

Any idea why there is more than 100% difference of byte-sizes between these two counts ? One 4.9 MB and the other 9.6 MB ?

Edit: Follow-up question at [How to find number of unique 'applications' in Debian jessie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159971/how-to-find-number-of-unique-applications-in-debian-jessie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how it says `[text/html]` for the second one, not `[text/plain]`. You're not fetching the package list, you're fetching a webpage that *contains* the package list, along with a bunch of other formatting.

But really, you want to fetch the compressed version; it will save both you and Debian time and money. You can do it with one command:

```
wget 'http://packages.debian.org/testing/allpackages?format=txt.gz' -O - | gunzip > allpackages.txt
```

Or count the lines directly (but note that this is off by a little due to extra lines at the beginning of the file):

```
wget 'http://packages.debian.org/testing/allpackages?format=txt.gz' -O - | gunzip | wc -l
```

Comment: what does `-O -` in the above command stand for ?

Comment: @shirish `-O` means "output to a file". `-` is a fairly common convention used by some programs to mean "use `stdin` or `stdout` (whichever makes sense)